# Controller being detected as a mouse and given mouse drivers

Tags: drivers, gamepad

I connected one of my gamepads after a while of not using it and when i used dmesg this was the result:

```
[103344.474003] usb 1-5.1: new full-speed USB device number 47 using xhci_hcd
[103344.605410] usb 1-5.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1038, idProduct=1430, bcdDevice= 1.75
[103344.605413] usb 1-5.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[103344.605415] usb 1-5.1: Product: SteelSeries Stratus Duo
[103344.616743] input: SteelSeries Stratus Duo as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.1/1-5.1:1.1/0003:1038:1430.004F/input/input53
[103344.616834] hid-generic 0003:1038:1430.004F: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [SteelSeries Stratus Duo] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5.1/input1
[103344.617505] hid-generic 0003:1038:1430.0050: hiddev3,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Device [SteelSeries Stratus Duo] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5.1/input2
[103344.644176] kauditd_printk_skb: 241 callbacks suppressed
```

If I'm interpreting this correctly, it's giving the controller mouse drivers. I tried some other controllers to be met with the same result. The controller is lighting up as if it's still connecting, but I can't use it. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 using Wayland.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain how you are trying to use this, and also what this is. What is the hardware, exactly? And in what context are you trying to use it? I don't know much about this, but treating a game controller as a mouse seems reasonable: it _is_ a mouse, it is supposed to do things you would otherwise do with a mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's using mouse drivers because it's a mouse in addition to being a gamepad. USB devices can have multiple interfaces, and each interface is handled by the operating system as if it were a separate device.

SteelSeries Stratus Duo has three USB interfaces:

- Interface 0 is Xbox 360 compatible
- Interface 1 is a standard HID mouse
- Interface 2 is a proprietary HID interface

I don't know why the device has a mouse interface since it doesn't seem to be used for any of the features described in the [manual](https://downloads.steelseriescdn.com/guides/StratusDuo_PIG_22.pdf).

On Linux, the `xpad` driver should recognize this gamepad's Xbox 360 interface when connected over USB. `xpad` needs to be recent enough to include the patch that added support for this gamepad:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/fe2bfd0d40c935763812973ce15f5764f1c12833